# Find the number of vertices that belong to all the maximum matchings of a general connected graph .

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

The given graph is connected but not necessarily bipartite. Please describe the complete approach with useful links , I read stuff related to augmenting paths but could not comprehend well.
An O(VE) approach will be good for me .
Though i would prefer O(V^2) approach (if it is known)

Comment: maybe this is better suited for another site, questions about algorithms don't receive good solutions here in general. There is a theoretical computer science site. Maybe it will be better received there.

Comment: Well I read the rules and itis "On-topic" for here . Also you`re right its well suited for cs but I find this platform better owing to some great people who would answer this sonn . :)

Comment: I didn't mean you should delete it here, I meant you should also ask there, I think you'll get a better answer there.

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ohh,Okay man.Sure I`ll do that then. Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there are some other solutions, but the simplest I can think of needs an understanding of the concept of augmenting paths. I don't know how much it will be useful to you, nevertheless I will post some hints, maybe it will clear some things.

**Hint:**

- The basic approach is to calculate for each $v \in V$ a maximum cardinality matching in $G_v = G \setminus_V \{v\}$, that is, a graph $G$ without $v$. If the cardinality of the matching decreases, that means $v$ has to be in all of them.
- You can observe that the above approach repeats itself a lot, to avoid it, we can first start with calculating some maximum cardinality matching $M$ for the whole graph $G$.
- Now, for each $v \in V$ you have three cases:

  1. $v \notin V(M)$: $M$ is a witness that $v$ does not belong to all maximum cardinality matchings.
  2. There is an augmenting path from $u$ in $G_v$ with matching $M \setminus \{u,v\}$, where $u$ is the pair of $v$ in $M$: this new matching is a witness that $v$ does not belong to all maximum cardinality matchings.
  3. There is no such an augmenting path: which proves via [this lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berge%27s_lemma) that maximum matching in $G_v$ has strictly smaller cardinality.
- You can observe that the last bullet still repeats itself a lot, that is, a lot of augmenting paths may end up in the same $M$-free vertex. Hence, instead of calculating augmenting paths from matched vertices you can search them from the other side, the vertices which are free in $M$.
- Finally, rather than starting the search from each free vertex separately, you can first merge them all into one super-source, where the whole approach simplifies down to calculating the even/odd level of each vertex.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thankyou so much..I think this is the intended solution. :)